# Scroll bars does not appear after loading ajax content on the page

Tags: html, css, ajax, scroll

I'm building a site where page content is loaded via ajax. I have everything working other than a quirk with Chrome and Safari. It is working with IE even!

The quirk is that when the page content loads and is longer than the index page height, scroll bars does not apear in either Chrome or Safari.

I found this ([In Chrome, page won't resize after Ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276492/only-in-chrome-page-wont-resize-after-ajax-load)) but the fix he made does not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer in the stack page you mentioned: [@Paul Tomblin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16361577/1927695). I don't know whether or not it is the answer of **that** question, but I guess (95%) that it's the answer of **your** question.

Suppose your content is in a class named `ajax_content`; you should run this code when the ajax request completes:

```
$('.ajax_content').each(function(){
    $(this).resize();
});
```

This code assures that all divs, spans, etc. with the `ajax_content` class will be resized. Remember that the `ajax_content` class should have the `scroll: auto;` attribute.

If you want to resize the whole page, you can use the answer I mentioned on **that** page:

```
$(window).resize();
```